# Jquery validator error mvc 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view **/Consolas/** that when I try to put a new record in my view **/Consolas/Agregar/**.

[image]

When I try to save and validate it with jquery send me to the page **/Consolas/Agregar/** and I lose the view of /Console/.

[image]

In the Add post I have the following:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Agregar(ConsolasDTO consolasDTO)
        {

            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _consolas.AgregarConsola(consolasDTO);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

**What could be this error?**

Comment: You probably need to make this an ajax call. Do you have any ajax code? Where do you _"validate it with jquery"_? Right now its doing exactly what you programmed it to do - return the View of Agregar when it fails validation - `return View();`

Comment: I dont have an ajax code, do I have to? because i made the required field on the model @zgood

Comment: Yes. You need to make it an ajax form submission. Currently you are doing a normal form submit (from your modal) and the server code is simply returning the view back.

Comment: If you have jQuery validate plugin, it can do client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether in you page those javascripts exists or not

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")'></script>
```

If not existing and install it from nuget/bower package and check it, then also you have same problem make sure that on submit not closing the pop-model if it is closing,then change the submit type to button and onclick on this submit the form submit through javascript close model after success message